# Set select's option value and fire change trigger properly

Tags: jquery

I have three select boxes

```
$("select#selectbox1").val(data.Ref_box1_ID.toString()).trigger('change');
$("select#selectbox2").val(data.Ref_box2_ID.toString()).trigger('change');
$("select#selectbox3").val(data.Ref_box3_ID.toString()).trigger('change');
```

and I have an issue: inside change event there's some code that loads options inside next selectbox but looks like it works only first one which selects correctly the option then triggering change event loads options in next selectbox; but second's select shows only first option which says "select an option..." and in third one it doesn't load anything at all, neither select any option..

What I could have missed in this code?... I tried to put also .blur() to refresh but no effects, neither adding before .trigger() the event attrib('selected','selected')...

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the code for the change event, since there is nothing wrong with the example you provided. (Perhaps you could use a for loop instead of duplicating code though)

Comment: If you are loading items asynchronously in the change event, that won't be complete when you try to select the value of the next selectbox.

Comment: Not related, but don't use `$("select#selectbox3")`. Its pointless as ID should always be unique. Use `$("#selectbox3")` instead

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<select id="selectbox1" />
    <option value="11"> 11</option>
    <option value="12"> 12</option>
    <option value="13"> 13</option>
</select>

<select id="selectbox2" />
    <option value="21"> 21</option>
    <option value="22"> 22</option>
    <option value="23"> 23</option>
</select>
<select id="selectbox3" />
    <option value="31"> 31</option>
    <option value="32"> 32</option>
    <option value="33"> 33</option>
</select>

$(function() {
    $('#selectbox1 , #selectbox2, #selectbox3').on('change', function() {

        var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        alert('Value of ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' is : ' + val);
    });

    $("#selectbox1").val('12').trigger('change');
    $("#selectbox2").val('23').trigger('change');
    $("#selectbox3").val('32').trigger('change');

});​
```

Did you trigger the events after defining the event or before that.. If later is done the event is not available yet for them to be triggered...

check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3UudT/)

Comment: Hello again everyone, in the change() event of each selector I load the next selector with data. I put also `$("#selectbox1").val(data.Ref_box1_ID.toString()).change(); $.when($("#selectbox1").triggerHandler('change')).done(function () { $("#selectbox1").blur(); $("#selectbox2").val(data.Ref_box2_ID.toString()); });` but it didn't selected the option in second select when it should... am I missing something maybe? Thanks all... cheers Luigi

Comment: Plus, if I put an `alert(message);` instead of `$("#selectbox1").blur();` the option is selected in #selectbox2...even if `blur()` would force event...so what I should have missed?... Thanks everyone, cheers!